# how to change directory before running command in windows command prompt

Tags: cmd

```
# run.bat
cmd /k python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\test.py"

cmd /k cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\" & python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\test.py"

cmd /k "cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\" & python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\test.py""
```

Question> I need to change the working directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\` then run the command `python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\test.py"`. Several methods have been tested and none of them give me the desired result. They all end up run the command without changing the working directory.

For example,
If I run c:\temp\run.bat, I expect the script first to change to directory of `C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\` then run the python script.

Comment: Escape the ampersand like `^&`, so you have: `cmd /K cd /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\" ^& python.exe "test.py"`. Anyway, do you really need the `cmd /K` part to open another command prompt window as there is already an instance opened by running `run.bat`?

Comment: Without starting a new instance of CMD, you can use `start "test" /b /w /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX" python.exe test.py`. That said, test.py should not require modifying the working directory. It can find its files relative to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Find the short names for the directory with space

```
dir /X
PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

Step 2: Quote all commands

```
cmd /k "cd C:\PROGRA~2\XXX\ & python.exe C:\PROGRA~2\XXX\test.py"
```

Comment: Step 0: disable creation of MS-DOS short names on the NTFS system volume. Step 1: fail. Relying on short names is an unreliable hack.